# We use angularjs 1.3 for our app using EC5, I want to start using Ecma6

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6

If our **entire front-end** uses **AngularJS** which currently uses **Ec5**, can I start using **ecma6** javascript in new / existing code?

Comment: Yes, but for compatibility you should transpile your new ES6 code back to ES5 in your build-process. Check out the Babel project (https://babeljs.io/)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what kind of browsers you need to support.

Please refer to:

[caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=ES6) to check if can directly use ES6.

Whatever, you can use Babel to do a conversion if you want to use ES6.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can!

I'd like to introduce you a **tutorial** of *Meteor Todo App with AnuglarJS* which is quite friendly with ES6.
https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/angular/creating-an-app

After you make a quick look upon it, you'll grasp the overall image of your intention, I bet.

Thanks